# What does BIOS Version/Date represent?

Tags: bios, laptop

I want to how old my laptop is? I bought it in Feb 2012 but obviously it was built before than that. By playing around - I saw that my BIOS Version/Date is 20th June 2011. So does that mean I can say my laptop was built/manufactured around 3 years ago?

[image]

Comment: The same tag/sticker that contains the serial number usually also has the manufactured date, often as something like `MFG Date YYMM` form so `MFG Date 1103` means it was built in March 2011. If it is small and hard to read try using a flashlight to increase the contrast.

Comment: Oh Ok. Thanks Brian. I would try it out. I think that tag/sticker is at the rear side of the laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the installed version of the BIOS is a timestamp for the version of the software that it's running, which is not an indication of the manufacture date of the hardware; it might be older or newer than the date displayed there.

They only way you'd be able to determine the age of the hardware would be if the manufacturer provides it in some way.